# programmatically or CLI to stop webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack-dev-server, angular-cli-v6

How to stop webpack-dev-server programatically of a CLI command against the port ?

Ctrl-C etc are good for manually stopping the server. We are basically killing it.

Is there a API that the server exposes to issue a STOP command or something ?

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this. Hopefully it's still relevant^^

According to documentation, the server can be opened and closed via node api as follows:

```js
// create instance
const server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), { });

// start
server.listen(8000, "localhost", err => {
    console.log("server started")
})

// close/stop
server.close(() => {
    console.log("server closed")
})
```

### Docs: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/webpack-dev-server

Comment: Angular CLI does not seem to expose something like this. I think what is needed in CLI is some http call to hit the dev server that should stop the server.